# using setinterval and clear interval in vuejs to fetch json according with the state delared in that json

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

im getting this json of my backend java to improve my Battle ShipGame, lets say:

```
 {
  "status": {
    "state": "Waiting for opponent in game"
  },

}
```

and this status might change according with the players status or condition in the game, receiving anytime a change is happening a new json with a new status.state, like;

```
"Welcome to game,place Ships Please"
"Welcome to game,Waiting for opponent to place ships"
"Ships in Coordenates, Shoot!!!"
"Enemy hasn't shot, wait for their shots"
```

then the idea of setting a setinterval to get my JSON updated every certain time , and for sure a clearinterval method to stop once the change is done, i made it with a hardcode way ... but im requesting for your help in order to make simpler this code .

first i declare in my data return a variable  in charge of fetching all data from my store in the setinterval

```
data(){
   return {

          fetchInterval:null,
   }
}
```

then in my created() i just got that variable in charge to make the fetch  and asign to it the setinterval specifying  where to make that request to and all else, like this:

```
    created() {
    this.fetchingGamePlayerId(this.gamePlayerId);

    this.fetchInterval=setInterval(() => {
      this.fetchingGamePlayerId(this.gamePlayerId)
    }, 3000);

  },
```

then i do initialize a watcher where in the hard code takes place :

```
watch:{
   getGamePlayerId(){
    const status=this.getGamePlayerId.status.state;
    if(status=="Waiting for opponent in game"){
      console.log('waiting for oppnents')
    }
    else{
      clearInterval(this.fetchInterval);
      if(status=="Welcome to game,place Ships Please"){
        this.fetchInterval=setInterval(() => {
          this.fetchingGamePlayerId(this.gamePlayerId)
        }, 3000);
      }
      else{
        clearInterval(this.fetchInterval);
        if(status=="Welcome to game,Waiting for opponent to place ships"){
          this.fetchInterval=setInterval(() => {
          this.fetchingGamePlayerId(this.gamePlayerId)
        }, 3000);
        }else{
          clearInterval(this.fetchInterval);
          if(status=="Ships in Coordenates, Shoot!!!"){
            this.fetchInterval=setInterval(() => {
          this.fetchingGamePlayerId(this.gamePlayerId)
        }, 3000);
          }else if(status=="Enemy hasn't shot, wait for their shots"){
                  this.fetchInterval=setInterval(() => {
                  this.fetchingGamePlayerId(this.gamePlayerId)
        }, 3000);
          }else{
             clearInterval(this.fetchInterval);
          }
        }
      }

    }
   }
}
```

Is there a way i could make this code shorter more dynamic and clean?......thanks in advance

Comment: why does this interval need to be reset all the time? Also i suggest to place spaces around `=` and proper tabbing to make the code easier to read.

Comment: The basic idea would be to have this `setInterval` function retrieve the data indefinitely, and have some sort of `watcher` watch the variable that this `setInterval` function sets.

Comment: first of all i'll suggest using a websocket in this case. second you can use one long switch-case and one function which will restart the timer. that will make you code much more readble and shorter. and btw you use a lot of insider if's